# host php files with CNAME

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have created a bucket bucket as `test.domain.com` as well added CNAME record for domain `test.domain.com`
I have used web set as `gsutil web set -m index.php -e missing.php gs://test.domain.com`
I have uploaded index.php file, `gsutil cp index.php gs://test.domain.com` but I cannot browse it as normal, when I try it to browse, it is getting downloaded to desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not execute PHP scripts like code when they are requested by users. Instead, it serves the PHP file itself to the user. `index.php` is a PHP file. Its content type is most likely something like `application/x-httpd-php`, and so your web browser decides that it's most likely something to be downloaded instead of displayed (although you could perhaps adjust the Content-Disposition to change this).

If this is actually HTML content, and the file is simply named `index.php`, you can adjust the Content-Type to `text/html` to have the object treated normally:

```
gsutil setmeta -h Content-Type:text/html gs://test.domain.com
```

N.B. *This will **not** cause your PHP script to execute*. Google Cloud Storage will never execute PHP scripts. If this is server-side code to be executed, you should consider AppEngine, which is very good at doing exactly this.